# search recurly invoice by time periods

Tags: invoice, recurly

Does Recurly allow to search invoices by time priod? say, last month, or last three months invoices? I did not find any on the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

On Recurly.com you can export invoices by time period https://app.recurly.com/go/exports/new

If you want search with PHP, You can use this example:

```
$invoices = Recurly_InvoiceList::get();
foreach ($invoices as $invoice) {
  $date = $invoice->created_at;
  $result = $date->format('Y-m-d');
  if($result > '2014-06-00'){
    print_R($invoice);
    print "\n";
  }
}
```